# Task queue with observables

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, observable

I have this situation: the user of my application can tap a button that will execute a task and the task take 2 seconds to finish. I want to create a queue to execute each task in a row, sequentially.

I'm using Ionic 3 with TypeScript.

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just grab a reference to the button, subscribe to the event stream of clicks, and use `flatMap` to pass off the click event to whatever async function does the task.  RxJS will ensure that everything is performed in order, and the beauty of Rx is that you don't have to manage any state.

Example:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
  // grab a reference to your button.  Doesn't matter how you do it.
  const button = document.getElementById('queueEventButton')

  // Create the stream of clicks
  Observable.fromEvent(button, 'click')
    .flatMap(this.doTask) // pass each click event off to the async process
    .scan( (count: number) => count + 1, 0) // this just counts the mouse click, useful for example
    .subscribe(count => console.log(`Response received for button click #${count}!`))
}

// example task that simulates two second processing
doTask(event: Event): Observable<Event> {
  return Observable.fromPromise(new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(event), 2000)
  }))
}
```

Comment: Was thinking about this last night and thought you probably would want to control the concurrency of the queue...here's a fiddle using rxjs@6 https://jsfiddle.net/helvetici/npx1cyL2/55/  You'd want to use `flatMapWithMaxConcurrent` for Rx 5 which I believe is what comes with Ionic 3 if I remember correctly though.  You'd have to look up the api changes between rx versions but the operators are the same.